# Value from Hidden Input field as an Actionlink Parameter

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

is there a way using Javascript or Jquery to use the value of a hidden field which i modify dynamically (depending on other stuff) to and actionlink helper?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change ActionLink parameters according to hidden input element value which is assigned by jquery or javascript then  you can use fallowing method. I assume that you have one parameter for "List" action and paramter is nullable. Also assume that you already set  "myHidden" element value.

```
<input type="hidden" id="myHidden">
<%=Html.ActionLink("Groups", "List", "Home", null ,new {@id="btnBrokerId"})%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
       var url= $("#btnBrokerId").attr("url");
       var id=$("#myHidden").val();
        $("#btnBrokerId").attr("url",url+'/'+id);
    });
</script>
```

If you are looking for something else let me know.